# Laravel Inserting data into a multiple pivot table

Tags: eloquent, pivot-table, laravel-livewire, laravel-9

I'm new in Laravel 9 but for my project I need to create a pivot table with multiple foreign keys. This is what the migration looks like.

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('language_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('language_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('proficiency_id')->constrained()->default(1)->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('motivation_id')->constrained()->default(1)->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('lang_status_id')->constrained()->default(1)->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Now, i'm trying to insert the data from a Livewire component, so I tried to create a Model for the pivot table but it didn't work. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried already?

Comment: Do not add `SOLVED` and your answer in your question; there is a separate answer section below. I have moved your answer to a community answer, but if you would like to add your own and get proper credit, I will remove it.

Comment: Got it! Thanks, I repost my answer properly this time.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the default values from the migration, from some reason they weren't working. The I used this in the Livewire controller:

```
public function addLanguage(Language $language)
{
    $user = auth()->user();
    $data = $this->validate();
    $language->id = $data['language'];        
    //create user language record
    $language->users()->attach($user->id, ['proficiency_id' => 1 , 'motivation_id' => 1, 'lang_status_id' => 1]);    
    //message
    //redirect
    return redirect(route('dashboard'));
}
```

And this worked. I hope this can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the default values from the migration, from some reason they weren't working. The I used this in the Livewire controller:

```
public function addLanguage(Language $language)
{
    $user = auth()->user();
    $data = $this->validate();
    $language->id = $data['language'];        
    //create user language record
    $language->users()->attach($user->id, ['proficiency_id' => 1 , 'motivation_id' => 1, 'lang_status_id' => 1]);    
    //message
    //redirect
    return redirect(route('dashboard'));
}
```

And this worked. I hope this can help someone else.